# ¿Cómo verificar el dato que ingreso para darle el tamaño a un array sea un número y letra?

Tags: java, java-8

-Quisiera poder hacer una verificación en al pedir un dato para darle el tamaño a un arreglo, pero si se ingresa letras o palabras (j,a,a,asdas) en vez de números (1,2,412,etc.) me muestre un error y que pida que reingrese el tamaño del array.

```
    public static void operacion(String decision){
        int tamanio=0;
    if(decision.equalsIgnoreCase("registrar empleados")){
        //Ingresar el tamaño del array
        tamanio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados a registrar: "));
        String nombre[] = new String[tamanio];
        String apellido[] = new String[tamanio];
        String edad[] = new String[tamanio];
        String cargo[] = new String[tamanio];
        String direccion[] = new String [tamanio];
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) {
            String title= "Empleado #"+(i+1);
            nombre[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el nombre del empleado "+(i+1), title, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            apellido[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el apellido del empleado "+(i+1), title, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            edad[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la edad del empleado "+(i+1), title, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            cargo[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el cargo del empleado: "+(i+1), title, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            direccion[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la dirección del empleado"+(i+1), title, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes crear un método que reciba un String y verifique si es numero o no;

```
private static boolean isNumeric(String cadena)
{
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(cadena);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        return false;
    }
}
```

y acá adentro hacer el manejo de excepciones, de paso podes meter el método dentro de un bucle para que lo solicite hasta que ingrese un numero;

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me parece bien tu idea, lo entiendaré :D.

Comment: De nada, dentro del mismo método podrías validar que sea mayor que 0, para que no lo cree y cosas así. Me quedo la duda de porque manejas empleados con Array de nombre y apellido, y directamente no usas un objeto empleado.

Comment: Bueno, te comento de que recién me estoy poniendo al día con los cursos de programación en la universidad recientemente me está empezando a gustar la programación y estoy empezando desde 0 repasando los cursos desde mi primer semestre hasta llegar al actual en el que estoy, actualmente ya estamos usando mvc, pero como recién estoy haciendo las tareas pasada de primer semestre, el profesor nos estuvo enseñando java y phyton a full consola xd, acabo todas las tareas del semeste que hago, un amigo me deja una tarea como proyecto. El si sabe como manejar java y por el conocí esta comunidad.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhh, comprendo, estaría bueno que te metas con el tema de objetos y la programación orientada a objetos. Para este tipo de tareas te sirve, por ejemplo, en tu código en algún momento puede que el nombre del empleado no coincida con su apellido.

Comment: Bueno terminando este proyecto de primer semestre, sigo con el de segundo semestre que trata todo sobre introducción a POO, luego el tercer semestre sigue todo sobre estructura de datos en java a pilas, lista enlazadas, listas doble, arboles y grafos y el siguiente semestre sigo con POO y MVC y así sucesivamente, actualmente estoy en el sexto semestre y me queda 2 años para acabar la carrera y creo que voy por un buen camino a esta velocidad que llevo

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo más conveniente es hacer manejo de la excepción [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) con la estructura `try catch()`. Según la API de Java 8

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

Es decir, la excepción ocurre cuando algún método intenta de convertir un string a un tipo numérico, y falla en el intento.

> si se ingresa letras o palabras en vez de números me muestre un error

Puedes intentar hacer la conversión `Integer.parseInt()` en el bloque try y con `catch()` mostrar ese error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dialog;
    int size = 0;

    dialog = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados a registrar: ");
    try {
        size = Integer.parseInt(dialog);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Se debe de ingresar un número entero!");
    }

    System.out.println(((Object)size).getClass().getName());
}
```

> y que pida que reingrese el tamaño del array.

Puedes implementar el mismo dialogo en el `catch()` para que haga la solicitud del dato nuevamente.

```
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Se debe de ingresar un número entero!");
    dialog = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la cantidad de empleados a registrar: ");
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias compañero, voy a intentarlo a tu forma :D.